# How do I implement int argc and char *argv[] in the main function?

Tags: c, eclipse

Say I write:

```
program -x +5 +r
```

where `-x`, `+5`, `+r` are the command-line switches.

`+5`: every five seconds , it sends a message

`+r` and `-x`: does stuff

How would I go about doing this in the int main function?  Would I need to have 
program as a class and have `-x`, `+5`, `+r` as the parameters of the class, or would each switch be a class of its own?  What if I wanted the command-line switches in a different order, such as:

```
   program +5 +4 -x
```

How would I also account for negative and positive signs?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As main is declared as `int main(char **argv, int argc)`, you just check each `argv[i]` for its value

Comment: Using a standard solution like getopts would be a good idea here.

Comment: a class? in c? are you sure it's c?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Wrong order.

Comment: @IngoBürk How does `getopt` work with `+r` like switches?

Comment: @klutt...yeah..stupid me. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This is my standard way of command line switch processing, adapted to accept + and - numbers:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i= 0;
    char filename[256];
    int number;
    int xOption= 0;

    /* format: prog -dfilename -xrs -n3 +5 -3
     * Switch chars are case insensitive and can be in any order
     */
LabelNextSwitch:
    while (++i < argc) {
        switch (argv[i][0]) {
        case '-':
                while (*++argv[i]) {
                    switch (toupper(*argv[i])) {
                    case 'D':
                            strncpy (filename, argv[i]+1, 256);
                            filename[255]= '\0';
                            goto LabelNextSwitch;

                    case 'N':
                            ++argv[i]; number = 0;
                            while (isdigit(*argv[i]))
                                number = number *10 + *argv[i]++ - '0';
                            goto LabelNextSwitch;

                    case 'X':
                            xOption= 1;
                            break;

                    case 'R':
                            // whatever
                            break;

                    case 'S':
                            // whatever
                            break;

                    default:
                            if (isdigit(*++argv[i])) {
                                number = 0;
                                while (isdigit(*argv[i]))
                                    number = number *10 + *argv[i]++ - '0';
                                number = -number;
                                goto LabelNextSwitch;
                            }
                            else
                                printf("Bad argument '%c', ignored.\n",*argv[i]);
                    } /* end switch (*argv[i]) */
                } /* end while (*++argv[i]) */
                break;
        case '+':
                if (isdigit(*++argv[i])) {
                    number = 0;
                    while (isdigit(*argv[i]))
                        number = number *10 + *argv[i]++ - '0';
                    goto LabelNextSwitch;
                }
                else
                    printf("Bad argument +%s, ignored.\n",argv[i]);
                break;
        default:
                printf("Bad argument %s, ignored.\n",argv[i]);
        } /* switch (argv[i][0]) */
    } /* end while (++i < argc) */
    return 0;
} /* end function */
```